# How to split a varchar like 'ABCxxz' into an upper case 'ABC' and a lower case 'xxz'?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

My data looks like:

```
ABCAbbz 
XXZxxz
ZAAAZa
Xaaaab
```

I need them into two columns:

```
ABCA   bbz 
XXZ    xxz
AAAZ   a
X      aaaab
```

I tried something with `COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN LIKE '%[a-z]'` but I don't know how to split.

(`AAxAx` will never happen.)

Comment: With a custom .Net assembly?
@VJHil It looks like SQL Server.

Comment: What database are you using?  And, is the length of the two parts always the same?

Comment: I'm using MS-SQL 2008. Another sample data could be `ZAAZZdb` into `ZAAZZ` and `db`.

Comment: is it always one case then the other? or is it sometimes `BaIzGz` to `BIG azz`

Comment: @arserbin3 Always one case then the other. The thing you said is impossible.

Comment: I get real suspicious when I see questions like this. Why not just `SELECT 'ABCA', 'bbz'`? That will do what you asked. Why is @arserbin3's suggestion “impossible”; there is no evidence of that from your question. I suspect there is some background information you're not telling us. Please tell us [what you're trying to accomplish](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/), not just what you're doing.

Comment: @DourHighArch why?, the requirements are pretty clear, op needs to split the string in 2 parts, one having the upper case letters and the other the lower case ones

Comment: And the example I said is indeed much more difficult (but not impossible)

Comment: @arserbin3 I think op is saying it's impossible that that column has that type of data

Comment: @arserbin3 I'm sooo sorry, I didn't mean it's impossible to be done (I'm very bad at SQL, I don't know what's possible). I meant it's impossible to occur in my data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with the `PATINDEX()` function and forcing it to be case sensitive:

```
SELECT
    SUBSTRING(
        t.MyColumn
        ,0
        ,PATINDEX('%[a-z]%', t.MyColumn COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN))
    AS uppercase
    ,SUBSTRING(
        t.MyColumn
        ,PATINDEX('%[a-z]%', t.MyColumn COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN)
        ,LEN(t.MyColumn))
    AS lowercase
FROM MyTable t
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/684c9/2)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4b857a/7

```
SELECT
LEFT(ColumnA, PATINDEX('%[abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz]%'
COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS,ColumnA)-1),
SUBSTRING(ColumnA, PATINDEX('%[abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz]%'
COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS,ColumnA),LEN(ColumnA))
FROM Table1
```

Comment: It worked. Could you please explain the whole [abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz], because I tried [a-z] and nope, it doesn't work.

Comment: @user1032613 On any version of MS Sql Server that supports `PATINDEX`, `[a-z]` works just fine. See the Sql Fiddle link on my answer for example. If it didn't work for you in `PATINDEX`, there was likely a typo.

Comment: @user1032613:it should work if you are using 'Latin1_General_BIN' .But in my case i was using 'Latin1_General_CS_AS'.
Hope this clears it.Try changing the same and you can see the expected output

Answer (score 0):

```
with t as (
select 'ZXXabc' as ColumnToScrub
union
select 'Abdsfsdf'
union
select 'YYYSKHFDSbc')

select 
distinct
    ColumnToScrub,
    left(
        ColumnToScrub,
        max(
            case 
                when ASCII( substring( ColumnToScrub , P.number , 1 ) ) between 65 and 90 then P.number 
                else 0 
            end
        ) over (partition by ColumnToScrub)  
    ) as UpperString,
    right(
        ColumnToScrub,
        len(columnToScrub) - 
        max( 
            case 
                when ASCII( substring( ColumnToScrub , P.number , 1 ) ) between 65 and 90 then P.number 
                else 0 
            end
        ) over (partition by ColumnToScrub) 
    ) as LowString
from t
left join master..spt_values P
            on P.number between 1 and len(t.ColumnToScrub)
            and type ='P'
```